# D3.js attr in json not working?

Tags: d3.js

I have just started using d3.js. I am trying to use json instead of keep on chaining ".attr". Consider my following code:

```
const w = 300, h = 100;

const padding = 2;
const dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];

const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr({
    x: (d, i) => i * w / dataset.length,
    y: d => h - d * 4,
    width: w / dataset.length - padding,
    height: d => d * 4,
    fill: d => `rgb(${d * 10},0,0)`
  })
```

When I was chaining .attr the bar chart was rendering properly. But now it is not working.